# Unable to connect to Windows 10 VM Using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, remote-desktop, windows-10

I am having trouble trying to connect to a new Windows 10 Pro virtual machine I created using VirtualBox 5 on Windows 7.  I created the VM using the Windows 10 template and used a virtual cd with the install ISO mounted.  after finishing the install and bringuping up the VM,  I enabled allowing remote desktop connections in the Windows 10 image.  i shut down the instance and added a 2nd network interface (The first one was NAT-ed) that I defined as Host Only adapter.  Then brought up the Windows 10 guest and attempted to RDC to the 198.*.*.* address that the 2nd adapter received from my host Windows 7 system.  I was unable to connect.   Any thoughts on what I may still need to do to make the connection.

Comment: Are you able to ping the VM (and vice-versa)? That could help narrowing down the problem. Also, I'm more familiar with VMware, but I keep it at NAT and local remote desktop still works - I use the ip that I get typing ipconfig inside the VM.

Comment: I can ping out but not in.  Thinking I need to tell windows 10 the second adapter network is a trusted network.  did note that there is no gateway address but I am thinking that is ok as the host only is effectively a switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can ping out but not in. Thinking I need to tell windows 10 the second adapter network is a trusted network.

Is there a firewall inside the VM? Try disabling it.

By the way, you don't need a second adapter to RDP in. The VM should have an IP address on the NAT interface and you can port-forward the hosts's 127.0.0.1:x to the VM's 192.168.1.2:x

This has the advantage of opening only one port and keeping the VM otherwise isolated from the host.

[image]

Comment: That works with allowances for VMWARE vs VIRTUALBOX (the interface is a little different.  I would still like to know if the two adapter config is possible.  if I get no other answers will accept this one in a day or two.